# URL Rewrite in DotNetNuke remove chunk of address (and read cookie?)

Tags: cookies, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke

I am working on a DotNetNuke application using the iFinity URL Master module. (that may be irrelevant, as a solution may be platform independent)

What I have is a site with addresses based on language.
so 
www.thesite.com/**en**/products/towels/redtowel
is the english version and
www.thesite.com/**de**/products/towels/redtowel
is the german version.

What I need to do is allow a user (who has already visited the site and set a cookie with their language) to be able to go to www.thesite.com/products/towels/redtowel and get to www.thesite.com/**en**/products/towels/redtowel if their cookie is set to english, and /**de**/products/towels/redtowel if it is set to german.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it was me and i didnt want to spend a lot of time programming I would look at something like this

http://www.snowcovered.com/snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=242&PackageID=10059

then it could do a redirect based on the cookie - otherwise with iFinity I think you can do that sort of  but not exactly.  (I may be wrong on that - not a fan of iFinity url rewriter)